# Using hash table parameter in function

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to build a hashtable in my script. Input is a parameter:

```
Param
(
[hashtable]$param
)
```

calling my function: `Foobar -Param 'Key, value'` does not work. Also tried:

```
Foobar -Param 'Key' = 'Value';
Foobar -Param Key Value
```

Error returned: `Cannot convert value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".`

How do I pass the arguments correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hashtable literal `@{}`:

```
Foobar -Param @{ Key = 'Value' }
```